# Running Server Method after Client Javascript Method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, onclientclick

Is it possible to setup an asp button so that when it is clicked, the client-side javascript will run, and then the server-side c# method will run, but only after the prior javascript has completed? The goal being when the client submits a form, the 3rd-party jscript does its thing and sends out the form data. When that is done, the server-side method will run, create the file it needs to, and then post it back so that the client can download it. I have both of these working separately, but trying to put them together has been the issue.

Doing some google-fu and S.O. searching has led me to think that maybe the option would be having `OnClientClick` and `OnServerClick` attached to the same `asp:button`? Or is there a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to provide the javascript method for `OnClientClick`. It will be executed before the postback takes place. You can even prevent it by returning `false`:

```
function JsMethodName() {
    // do something...
    // return true; // postback
    // return false; // no postback
}

<asp:Button ID="ButtonID" 
    OnClientClick="return JsMethodName();" 
    OnClick="ServerMethod" runat="server" Text="ButtonText" />
```

Comment: So I ran something like this, and tested the true with a `setTimeout()` of 3 seconds. Must be something to do with the different browser threads? The file downloaded before I got the alert within setTimeout. The false return does stop the server from creating anything, though, which is desired.